# Has Intellij Idea(2020.1) removed maven auto-import dependencies?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to find why maven dependencies are not shown under external libraries in Intellij. This used to happen automatically in previous versions. Is there a way to enable it or manually import?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try to select "Any changes" in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools".

[image]

[image]